# fetch rejects request with response code 200 when doing cors request with authentication

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have an api on `localhost:80` which I want to request from `localhost:3000` using `fetch`. The site at port 80 is secured using htpasswd. When directly accessing the url, I get results in json format. The request results in  `401 Unauthorized`. So we've got two "problems" to solve here. Having only one of them would have been easy.

- CORS
- Authentication

Well, my approach was to set `mode: 'cors'` and `credentials: 'include'` in `RequestInit` as well as setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header server-side to `*` (for testing purposes only).

That request results in a status code `200` but a rejection by `fetch` with a `console.warn` that `mode: 'cors'` doesn't work alongside with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. So I thought, setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `localhost:3000` or `http://localhost:3000` might finally solve the problem, but it didn't.

It turned out that now I had an url mismatch: The response status code was still `200` but it still got rejected because `localhost:3000` didn't match the requesting url which, as far as I know, *did* match.

So, do anyone of you know what I missed and did wrong?

client on port 3000:

```js
let result = await fetch('http://localhost/path/to/resource', {
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
});
```

server on port 80:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the exact value of the `Origin` request header? Also, does your request send a CORS preflight (OPTIONS) request?

Comment: As @JaromandaX implied, given you're including credentials, it's likely there's an `OPTIONS` call. Look in the network console of the browser to see if there are any errors there, and to see the exact response.

Comment: oh, the server will also need to send `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` response - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Comment: What’s the exact error message that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I decided not to put effort in a problem I would only have in development. Nonetheless, thanks for the replies!